# How can I access list values in a WFFM list field?

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm trying to make a poll results page with the results from a WFFM form. I initially took all the entered data(using AnalyticsFormsDataProvider), queried it, and then displayed the results. However, if no one votes for a particular answer, it wouldn't be in the entered data so it wouldn't show.

I want to display that the field had 0 votes, so now I'm trying to compare the possible answers to the queried list. However, I can't seem to find a way to access the values of the list items. Does anyone know the class those values are stored in and/or how to access them?

I'm using WFFM 8.1 rev. 151217 (Update-1) with MVC. It's a radio list field if that makes a difference from the other list fields.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you save me a few minutes of digging and show me the code that you're using right now to query the list? Also, can you be sure to share the name of the class  that each "Field" is a type of?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to get WFFM field as regular Sitecore item via standard API.

Available list items values are saved in "Parameters" and "Localized Parameters" fields. You can use Sitecore.Form.Core.Utility.ParametersUtil from Sitecore.Forms.Core to parse values saved in these fields.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but could you expand on the parsing some more? I'm now able to get the localized parameter field, but it's still returning the cryptic value (%3cquery+t%3d%22...). I'm trying to work with that util class, but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

This data is stored on your `Radio List` Field's `Item` in the fields `Parameters` and `Localized Parameters`.

If your code is within the Form's `SaveAction` or a `Validator` you will have access to the Field in the for `AdaptedResultList` args the `SaveAction` or via `this.classAttributes["fieldid"]` for the `Validator`. That will be enough for you to get the `Radio List` Item and then the Parameter fields.

If your code is not in a `SaveAction` / `Validator` I recommend passing the Form Item into your code possibly by `Datasource` and then retrieving the Radio List Item from that.

Finally the Items of the your Radio List field is stored in the format

```
<item><item>
```

If your radio items are actually items you will want to parse them using a regex

```
var regexItems = new Regex(@"<item>(.*?)</item>".ToLower());
var itemNodes = regexItems.Matches(FieldItem["Parameters"].ToLower());
```

Then you should be free to play with the list for your poll